# PHP XML Parser with ability to define expect multiple values

Tags: php, xml, xsd, wsdl, dtd

We have to write readers to input xml data on a regular basis, and a common bug we get is where, if you have a node that can have multiple children, and in a particular instance there's only 1 child, then the resulting array or object will return the single child rather than array of children.

For example, parsing:

```
<parent>
  <child name="Bill">
  </child>
  <child name="John">
  </child>
</parent>
```

Will return an object or array like:

```
[child] => array(
   [0] => array(
      [name] => "Bill"
   )
   [1] => array(
      [name] => "John"
   )
)
```

Whereas parsing:

```
<parent>
  <child name="John">
  </child>
</parent>
```

Will return:

```
[child] => array(
   [name] => "John"
)
```

I know that, on a case by case basis, we can check these things manually like:

if( isset( $parent[ 'child' ][ 'name' ] ) ) $parent[ 'child' ] = array( $parent[ 'child' ] );

But it's something you have to remember to do all the time and it pops up often in bug reports. Many of these xml sources already have WSDL specifications or DTD's which do specify that an element may have multiple occurrences, as below, so the information we need is already there but none of the parsers we use seem to be smart enough to use that information when structuring the result.

```
<s:complexType name="parent">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="child" nillable="true" type="tns:child"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="child">
<s:complexContent mixed="false">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="name" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:extension>
</s:complexContent>
</s:complexType>
```

Is there an xml parser available that is smarter with its interpretation of data that knows when a set of elements is a list based on the DTD, XSD, WSDL, and always returns an array of values instead of using best guesses to collapse single values, or is it possible to set the parser to always make every child node into an array which, while a bit unwieldy when coding, means the structure is at least always consistent regardless of the number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Soap extension has a [SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) feature option.